# Custom Tabs opened by Gmail app ignore Set-Cookie header

Tags: android, cookies, android-customtabs

I have no clue whether I am right with this question on Stack Overflow but I believe this bevahior is intentional and I am missing out something.

I have an application that sends authentication links via email. When a user opens such a link, the server sets a cookie and redirects the user to the authenticated URL. That works fine for any browser and OS except Android's custom tabs opened by the Gmail app. It simply ignores the `Set-Cookie` header and never sends that cookie again to the server and therefore fails to authenticate.

Log from `tcpdump -i eth0 -A port 8080`

```http
GET /blog/post/6/auth?token=SECRET HTTP/1.1
X-Forwarded-Host: example.org
Host: example-app:8080
Connection: close
X-Forwarded-For: 175.187.223.93
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
accept-language: de-DE
dnt: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-dest: document
referer: android-app://com.google.android.gm/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Fri, 22 Mar 2024 15:06:43 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: /blog/post/6
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.AuthCookie=CfDJ8NUlF4VoiyyMsZqiYlq0_-ra9hnivA6_Jl0fdo3qZD43oy_dXvYlfXBrznygZUsFz9dj38D0H2MQLm_gAEa7zVPK017v3bu_iH_dYkvyyDGFC-_mnN7mDlFZNhMpswLiQ6f5jEmLs7OgR07jvhshjVjZYIGAsEiOYSp9yuBAm5iIBgR_4QaMB8-HSYCedVNvEYcnoIfu3ue1fQMC5D-VgGi95OcYp7vhmK88oA3lHV5t0e4uPF2y5lyPZkXLoptFA67l--qaDzIBbBz2VLSZbQ7_VCdY80MNkin4cEvNZ_r4V268LgAuyerJndgy-Z7M-WAEpdQ2XKcXoa-lQSsEP7KXATg1CLKSCEJEcWU4sQ2dRYNXA7VHBG0b3iBlab4G1DWA3l7twO0Y-jGFMrviYZm; expires=Sun, 21 Apr 2024 15:06:44 GMT; path=/blog; secure; samesite=strict; httponly

GET /blog/post/6 HTTP/1.1
X-Forwarded-Host: example.org
Host: example-app:8080
Connection: close
X-Forwarded-For: 175.187.223.93
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
dnt: 1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?1
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Android"
referer: android-app://com.google.android.gm/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

Environment

- Android 14
- One UI 6.0
- Gmail 2024.02.11.610508537.Release
- Google Chrome 122.0.6261.90
- Firefox 122.1.0